# In Sibelius 8 or later how do you add a staff to an instrument?

Tags: sibelius

My instrument (strings) has one staff, I'd like it to be a grand staff, and later three staves. How do I do this please?

In Musescore it's just Instruments - Add staff, but I can't see anything similar in Sibelius.

Comment: We have a prolific and esteemed contributor with the very same name here! It's likely to cause confusion, particularly with comments, which are merely attributed by name. Would you consider adding, say, an initial after your name, to obviate any potential confusion? Thanks

Comment: How on earth did the system allow two contributors to choose the same name?   This is our fault, not his!

Comment: There're like a million people on StackExchange, guys, it'll be ok :)

Comment: For a second I thought the *other Richard* had come across this question, and modestly refused your proposal. @Tim I guess I just proved your point, huh.

Comment: @LaurencePayne - I'm certainly not blaming Richard - either of them ( and maybe  a plethora of others...) but if a comment is headed '@Richard', who receives it? And, if it's from 'Richard', it's useful to be aware of which Richard. Pointless, confusing and unnecessary. Maybe the system needs a tweak..?  Exactly as the above comment points out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it what you want?
[image]

### Adding Extra staves to an instrument

First of all, you need to make sure you have 3 instruments. If you missed this step when creating the score, then you just need to press "I" on the keyboard to add extra staves to the instrument. Click the insturment you want to add staves, then click the **"Below"** button under the **"Extra Staff"** section
[image: add instruments]

### Hiding empty staves

Assume your music starts with one staff, and then notes appear on the second staff, and finally the third staff. Then you can acheive the above result by doing:
Layout --> Hide Empty Staves
[image]

### Dynamics for all staves

I am not awaer of any way to check the dynamcis for all staves. Even if it is one single instrument with multiple staves, the dynamics changes still apply to one single staff at a time.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want multiple instruments, just one instrument with multiple staves. Otherwise for instance if I add *mf* to one staff it won't affect the others.

Comment: Is there a way to make dynamics affect the entire system (all parts) a la Musescore?

Comment: @Richard I have updated the ansewer. But even you have a single instrument, you still need to add dynamcis to each of the staff. They are still independent to each other.

Comment: Alright thanks if this is the only way I'll mark it as answer, but it seems like a hack. For instance in a normal grand piano staff I definitely **don't** have to add dynamics twice. I don't see why I should have to if I add a third staff. Gah, I wish Musescore had better playback, or Dorico was more complete. They all have horrible flaws :(

Comment: @Richard For the case of grand piano staff, the dynamics applies to both staves only if you put it in between the two staves. If you put the dynamics below the bass clef, it applies to only left hand; if you put the dynamics above the treble clef, it applies to only right hand. And you are right, no single software is perfect, it is a sad truth.

Comment: Not really a flaw, in a notation program.  When a violin section goes divisi, each group of players needs to be told the dynamic.    If you didn't want to treat the staves as separate players, why use separate staves?

Answer (score 1):

'Add stave below' (in the Add Instruments page) plus 'Hide empty staves' will create the staves you asked for.

But it won't get you out of adding dynamics for each stave.  The two systems in my screenshot will sound very different.

Note, however, that all three instances of *'ff'* can be entered at once, by selecting all three staves before pressing ctrl-E then ctrl-fff.   Sibelius is even clever enough to enter it where an instrument next has a note, not on a rest.

And, of course, when live players get to use the parts, they'll need to see dynamics for each stave.

[image]